# How to learn about configurations in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

It's hard for me to write a `docker-compose.yml` for the complex environment.

Just like Kafka, I can learn some configurations in the Docker Hub where Kafka is in. But I found some others I have never seen in other people's projects.

```yaml
 environment:
      # KRaft settings
      - KAFKA_CFG_NODE_ID=2
      - KAFKA_CFG_PROCESS_ROLES=controller,broker
     KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@98.142.138.1:9093,1@98.142.137.2:9093,2@98.142.138.3:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS=0@10.11.12.14:9093,1@10.11.12.15:9093,2@10.11.12.19:9093
      - KAFKA_KRAFT_CLUSTER_ID=zhcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
      # Listeners
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,CONTROLLER://0.0.0.0:9093
      - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://98.142.138.3:9092
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_CFG_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES=CONTROLLER
      - KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=PLAINTEXT
      # security
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_USERS=vuser
      - KAFKA_CLIENT_PASSWORDS=vuserpwd123
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_CONTROLLER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_USER=vuser
      - KAFKA_CONTROLLER_PASSWORD=vuserpwd123
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_MECHANISM_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_USER=vuser
      - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PASSWORD=vuserpwd123
      - KAFKA_CFG_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM= 
      - KAFKA_CFG_SASL_ENABLED_MECHANISMS=PLAIN
      - KAFKA_TLS_TYPE=JKS
```

Some of them do not exist in Docker Hub, I don't know how to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the `bitnami/kafka` image, then from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka):

> Any environment variable beginning with `KAFKA_CFG_` will
> be mapped to its corresponding Apache Kafka key. For example, use
> `KAFKA_CFG_BACKGROUND_THREADS` in order to set `background.threads` or
> `KAFKA_CFG_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE` in order to configure
> `auto.create.topics.enable`.

[Here you can find the documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#configuration) for all configuration parameters.